# Linear, durable and programmable mouse?

Tags: mice

I'm looking for options to replace my current mouse which has some interesting features, but not all I want.

**Must-Haves / Hard Requirements:**

- Price must be <100€ in Germany
- The configuration software must work with Windows 10 Creator's Update
- The mouse needs to have at least two clickable buttons additionally to a standard clickable scroll-wheel and the left- and right mouse buttons
- The configuration software must be able to assign the following actions:

  - Open Windows Explorer (win-key + e)
  - Copy (Ctrl+c)
  - Paste (Ctrl+v)
  - Open Start (win-key)
  - Double-Click
- The mouse *must* feature a sensor that either has no hardware mouse acceleration or where it can be turned off through the configuration software
- It must be wired and use USB as its interface
- It must feature a closed design, that is it must not be / look like the Mad Catz RAT series

***Really* Nice-To-Haves:**

- The mouse allows me to program 4 of the 5 above listed functionalities at once, ie it has either 4 buttons or features something like a "shift" button
- The mouse works out of the box with Windows using default drivers (HID)
- The mouse can save its programming and apply it to new machines without the configuration software installed (ie if I configure ExtraButton1 to be "copy" it must work on all machines out-of-the-box)
- The mouse should last >5 years, for the sake of comparability we set this requirement equal with "has >2 years of manufacturer warranty"

**Neat features:**

- A configurable lift distance
- A configurable DPI value
- Configurable weight
- "Big" size

Comment: I haven't heard of mice having hardware mouse acceleration. I've only seen the option of mouse acceleration in windows' mouse settings (which I usually turn off).

Comment: @BennettYeo [_"The problem with hardware acceleration caused by the sensor in the mouse is that it can be both positive and negative, can be affected by the surface the sensor is used on, and can be unstable/inconsistent."_](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=56240.0) ie, it exists.